# On finding the matrix of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be the linear operator on$\Bbb C^2$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,0)$.Let B be the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb C^2$ and let B'=$\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ be the ordered basis defined by $\alpha_1=(1,i)$,$\alpha_2=(-i,2)$.what is the matrix of T relative to the pair B,B'?

**My attempt:**

$T(1,0)=(1,0)=x(1,i)+y(-i,2)$  and    $T(0,1)=(0,0)=z(1,i)+w(-i,2)$

$\therefore (x-iy,ix+2y)=(1,0)$  and  $(z-iw,iz+2w)=(0,0)$

$\therefore$ on solving $x-iy=1$ and $ix+2y=0$ we get $x=2$ and $y=-i$ and on solving $z-iw=0$ and $iz+2w=0$ we get $w=0$ and $z=0$.
therefore required matrix is \begin{pmatrix}2&0\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}

Am I correct?If yes, then is there another method to solve this type of problem beside solving equation directly?if yes,then please describe that method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

Another method to get this answer would be to let $C=[T]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $P=[I]_{B^{\prime},B}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-i\\i&2\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $[T]_{B,B^{\prime}}=P^{-1}C=\begin{bmatrix}2&i\\-i&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\-i&0\end{bmatrix}$.